# Wordpress the changes I made in the html file are not working

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I downloaded the codes of this site with the wp file manager plugin. When I made changes to the codes and uploaded them again, I saw that the changes did not work. The path to the file I changed looks like this: `www/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/myftpupload.com/index-https.html`. My main goal is to delete the loaded and unused javascripts on the homepage of the site and change the format of the images to .webp without using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure, you have added the right name of your file during uploading...

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't use *any* `*.html` files to generate the display of the pages of a website, it uses `*.php` files for that purpose. So the file you are talking about can't be a file Wordpress is really using as a basis for its display.

Comment: Actually, I want to remove the unnecessary javascripts in the html file, and I also want to change the extensions of the images on the site. Can you give an idea about this?